# How to retrieve all connected bluetooth peripherals

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to get a list of all connected Peripherals to an iPhone. I have a Bose Soundlink connected but it doesn't show up in my app. I don't know the UUID so am passing [] as this should get all I think?

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    var message = ""

    switch central.state {
      case .poweredOn:
         message = "Bluetooth LE is turned on and ready for communication."

         // scan for ALL devices
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)

         let connectedPeripherals = self.centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: []) 
        // WILL [] RETURN ALL CONNECTED PERIPHERALS?
        print("connectedPeripherals are \(connectedPeripherals)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it really BLE, not just Bluetooth classic?

Comment: Please don't add thanks to your posts, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Comment: Good spot Larme, The Bose is indeed Bluetooth Classic. Damn!

Comment: @richc Do you remember how you solved that?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get all connected peripherals, my suggestion is: add string 180A as a parameter to retrieveConnectedPeripherals. All Bluetooth Smart devices implement the DEVICE INFORMATION (180A) service (at least this one).