# Retrieve connected peripherals returns empty array

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I have an Android phone connected to an iPhone via bluetooth. Using `CBCentralManager` I tried to retrieve all connected peripherals as such:

```
let data = centralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [])        
let data1 = centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [])
```

I passes an empty array because I thought it would return me everything, but instead I get an empty array in both cases.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525275/how-to-retrieve-all-connected-bluetooth-peripherals) post, it's probably because the connection is not BLE but Bluetooth classic.

How can I still retrieve the Android BT connection?

**Edit**:

I also tried to add an array of services:

```
let data1 = centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: "0xFD6C"), CBUUID(string: "0xFD69"), CBUUID(string: "0xFD5A"), CBUUID(string: "0xFD59"), CBUUID(string: "0xFD4B"), CBUUID(string: "0xFDDB"), CBUUID(string: "0xFD7E")])
```

The numbers are taken from [here](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf) for a Samsung devices.
Still I got an empty array.

Comment: I'm the one who made the comment at the time. At the time CoreBluetooth was only for BLE devices, which isn't the case anymore (Can't find which iOS version is needed though). So it shouldn't be the case here.

Comment: @Larme Do you have an idea what might be the problem in this case?

Comment: You need to supply the identifiers or the services.  You can't pass an empty array (well, you can, but you will get an empty response).  Core Bluetooth is still mostly only for BLE devices.  After iOS 13 you can use it with *dual mode* peripherals - Say a headset that uses a legacy headset profile and a BLE Gatt connection for control/configuration, but you can't use Core Bluetooth for pure legacy peripherals

Comment: @Paulw11, thanks. I tried to put an array of services according to: https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf, but still got an empty array. Do you know what else I can do to find my Android connection?

Comment: How are you making the connection?  You would typically need a compatible app on both sides; one acting as the central and the other acting as a peripheral.

Comment: @Paulw11, I manually connected my iPhone to my Android through the BT settings.
My bottom goal is to get a list of all the devices that connected to my iPhone via Bluetooth.

Comment: But what sort of connection? There is no generic connection between iOS and Android devices; there has to be some profile involved.  I don't believe that there is any way to get a list of Bluetooth devices connected to an iOS device.

Comment: @Paulw11, what I mean is that I turned on BT on Android and iPhone, when the iPhone found the Android, I just clicked on it in the list and now I see in BT setting on my iPhone that I'm connected to my Android phone. That's what I mean when I say that they are connected.

Comment: @Paulw11, one more thing, if for instance I play music on wireless speaker which is connected by bluetooth to my phone, won't `centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals` be able to find it?

Comment: No, that is managed using audio routes in the AV framework

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232163/discussion-between-paulw11-and-keselme).